# Disable text select with JavaScript and/or CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a text button using simple span and formatting the text and providing onclick behaviour. The problem is when a user clicks on the button, it sometimes highlights the text of the button.

I want to avoid such behaviour, because it looks damn ugly when the text is selected. Is there any CSS/JavaScript/(jQuery) content I can use to avoid this?

Comment: I see and smile when all mentions of javascript are suffixed by "jquery". Sometimes I feel that the community is getting out of touch with legacy javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS rule to disable text selection highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
spanid.onselectstart = function() {return false;} // ie
spanid.onmousedown = function() {return false;} // mozilla
```

First result on Google by the way...

**extra**

```
$('#spanid').selectstart(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: +1 for such a simple solution :) I didn't realize it would be this simple

Answer (score 5):

For a CSS solution:

```
.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* Isn't Konquerour dead? */
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

But, [looking here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), CSS solution is not enough in late 2013, so you should add some javascript. There are good answers around.

Answer (score 1):

You can just write:

```
$('#spanid').disableSelection();
```

Comment: just to clarify, this requires jquery library.