# Disable click on a div

Tags: javascript

I want to disable click on a certain `<div>` so that when you select the text on it, the text doesn't select.

I tried writing `onclick="return false;"` like in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/X6hqD/ but it doesn't work.

How can it work? (My goal isn't just disabling the select, it's the whole click).

Comment: try a search on stackoverflow : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920049/javascript-css-disable-text-select

Comment: @benoît Thank you, can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [css rule to disable text selection highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('div1').onmousedown = new function ("return false");
```

Comment: Finally, I accepted your answer because it's the real answer to my question (to disable click). The other anwers were working but were disabling other things too that aren't disabled with you answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable selection of the text only, use:

```
<div onselectstart='return false;'>
    text
</div>

div{
   -moz-user-select: none;-webkit-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select:none;o-user-select:none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: `onselectstart` is for IE `-moz-user-select: none;` is for firefox and `-webkit-user-select: none;` is for safari and google chrome. For what is `user-select: none;`?

Comment: @Mageek it's for internet explorer who does not understand user-select.

Comment: `user-select: none;` is for internet explorer who does not understand `user-select` ?????????

Comment: @Mageek misread, onselect = IE, user-select = standard, and browser who don't implement it according to the specs (older ones) you need the vendor-prefixes (-moz, -o, -webkit, -ms).

Comment: you mean `-khtml-user-select: none;` and `-o-user-select: none;` ?

Comment: @Mageek it's like with all the other css attributes. You have a standard (`user-select`) and then you have to add the vendor prefixes for browsers with older implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this CSS

```
<style type="text/css" media="print,screen" >
  .unselectable {
     -webkit-touch-callout: none;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     -khtml-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
     -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none;
   }
    </style>

<div class="unselectable">
asdasdsadsadsad<br>asdasdasd
</div>

<br><br>

<div>
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq<br>asdasdasd
</div>
```

Comment: I have added the css for IE also

Comment: IE needs js-fallback. He does not support user-select.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="div-test-id" style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:yellow;">Lorem ipsum</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var div_click_escape=function(eventObject){
      return false;
};

$(function(){
    $("#div-test-id").click(div_click_escape);
    $("#div-test-id").mousedown(div_click_escape);
    $("#div-test-id").mouseup(div_click_escape);
}
</script>
```

Will avoid to select the text.