# How can i disable onclick event after successful ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to disable onclick event after successful ajax request

```
<div class="report_button" id="report_button" title="Reportthis" style="width:65px;height:15px;" onclick="reported_text(user_id,lead_id);">Report</div>
```

this is my div which i want to disable div after clicked

```
function reported_text(user_id,lead_id){
    new Ajax.Request("/agent/report/lead-refund",
    {
        method:"POST",
        parameters:"user_id=" + user_id + "&lead_id=" + lead_id ,
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            alert("Thank you for Response");
            jQuery('#report_button').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        },
        onFailure: function(transport){

            $('tag_error_status').innerHTML = '';
            alert("Unsuccessful request processing. This will be rectified soon.");
        }
    });
}
```

is there any way to do this. and this div is used for many users, i have to do it in such a way so that it only disable for particular user.

Comment: Why not use a button instead of a div?

Comment: attr disabled is just for type buttons doesn't work on div ... you will need to use off()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 new Ajax.Request("/agent/report/lead-refund",
    {
        method:"POST",
        parameters:"user_id=" + user_id + "&lead_id=" + lead_id ,
        onSuccess: function(transport){
            alert("Thank you for Response");
            jQuery('#report_button').hide();
        },
        onFailure: function(transport){

            $('tag_error_status').innerHTML = '';
            alert("Unsuccessful request processing. This will be rectified soon.");
        }
    });
```

You can use hide function to do so... or you can use `$("#report_button").attr("onclick","")`

Comment: i have to disable only not hide

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you added the listener try the one that suits:
if you used `$(document).on` then use:

```
$(document).off("click", "#report_button");
```

if you used $("#report_button").on then use:

```
$("#report_button").off
```

or just use:

```
$("#report_button").click(function(){ return false; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable click like this:

```
document.getElementById("report_button").onmousedown = new function ("return false");
```

Here is where I found this code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11186866/4028085)