# Basic primitives Organigram -disable click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have iframe which contains my organigram(basicprimitives). 
The question is how to disable all clicks in this iframe? And for later enable it for just specific items(class name).
Code bellow is showing iframe selection and organigram properties(sector_options).

```
document.getElementById('organigram-iFrame').contentWindow.sector_options.
```

If there is anyone who can help me solve this thing out, I would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to replace the onmousedown event as shown in the answer here:

[Disable click on a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186666/disable-click-on-a-div)

```
document.getElementById('organigram-iFrame').onmousedown = new function ("return false");
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Basic Primitives diagrams support navigationMode option disabling all user interactions if needed.

navigationMode = primitives.common.NavigationMode.Inactive;

Try web site demos to confirm required behavior:
[image]